# MySQL - Slow query when getting previous row data

Tags: mysql

I have this query that takes  0.04 seconds to load

```
SELECT sg.Name AS 'Customer Name', 
m.meter_id AS 'Serial No', 
DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y/%m/%d') AS Date,  
MAX(wh_total) AS Present
FROM meter_data m 
INNER JOIN enrollment e 
ON e.Meter_Id = m.meter_id AND e.Status = 1 
INNER JOIN company_subgroup sg 
ON sg.Id = e.Subgroup_Id 
INNER JOIN company_group g 
ON g.Id = sg.Group_Id 
WHERE date(dateTime) BETWEEN '2018/06/01' AND '2018/06/30' 
AND m.meter_id = '12345' 
AND m.wh_total < 1000000000 
GROUP BY date(datetime)
```

But if I added this 'Previous' select column, it takes around 20 seconds to execute.

```
SELECT sg.Name AS 'Customer Name', 
m.meter_id AS 'Serial No', 
DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y/%m/%d') AS Date, 
// THIS (main issue)
COALESCE((SELECT MAX(wh_total) FROM meter_data WHERE date(dateTime) < date(m.dateTime) AND meter_id = '12345' 
AND wh_total < 1000000000 GROUP BY date(dateTime) ORDER BY date(dateTime) DESC LIMIT 1),0) AS Previous,
//
MAX(wh_total) AS Present,
// THIS (But I guess this does not affect the query that much since it only substract the two columns) 
ROUND(MAX(wh_total) - MIN((SELECT Previous)),2) AS Consumption 
//
FROM meter_data m 
INNER JOIN enrollment e 
ON e.Meter_Id = m.meter_id AND e.Status = 1 
INNER JOIN company_subgroup sg 
ON sg.Id = e.Subgroup_Id 
INNER JOIN company_group g 
ON g.Id = sg.Group_Id 
WHERE date(dateTime) BETWEEN '2018/06/01' AND '2018/06/30' 
AND m.meter_id = '12345' 
AND m.wh_total < 1000000000 
GROUP BY date(datetime)
```

Basically, the Previous column gets the data of the previous row. The query looks something like this:

```
Customer Name | Serial No | Date       | Previous | Present | Consumption
ABC           | 12345     | 06/01/2018 | 0        | 1       | 1
ABC           | 12345     | 06/02/2018 | 1        | 3       | 2
ABC           | 12345     | 06/03/2018 | 3        | 8       | 5 
ABC           | 12345     | 06/04/2018 | 8        | 10      | 2
```

I tried to use LAG(column) to get previous row data unfortunately MySQL version is 5.6. Is there any way to optimize this query?

Comment: Use self-join instead of the subquery.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT sg.Name AS 'Customer Name', 
        m.meter_id AS 'Serial No', 
        DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y/%m/%d') AS Date, 
        COALESCE(mx.max_total,0) AS Previous,
        MAX(wh_total) AS Present,
        ROUND(MAX(wh_total) - MIN((mx.max_total)),2) AS Consumption 
FROM meter_data m 
        INNER JOIN enrollment e ON e.Meter_Id = m.meter_id AND e.Status = 1 
        INNER JOIN company_subgroup sg ON sg.Id = e.Subgroup_Id 
        INNER JOIN company_group g ON g.Id = sg.Group_Id 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT date(dateTime) as dt,  MAX(wh_total) max_total
                    FROM meter_data 
                    WHERE meter_id = '12345' AND wh_total < 1000000000 
                    GROUP BY date(dateTime)) mx on mx.dt < date(m.dateTime)
WHERE date(m.dateTime) BETWEEN '2018/06/01' AND '2018/06/30' 
AND m.meter_id = '12345' 
AND m.wh_total < 1000000000 
GROUP BY date(m.datetime)
```

Note: if that in-line return more than one row then restrict that by adding some more condition

Comment: This query took 0.8 seconds, but all previous row returns same value. I'll try to look onto this.  Maybe just some conditions.

Comment: I'm almost there, but I can't reference the date(m.dateTime) from meter_data inside the Subquery. I wanted to do '.. AND wh_total < 1000000000 AND dt < date(m.dateTime)' inside the Subquery. If I put it on the ON condition, it will just return NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. this store the Previous data in a user var.

I have changed it again. The MAX function got the error. so i have put it
in a subquery.

```
SELECT r.`Customer NAME`, r.`SERIAL NO`, r.`DATE` , @prev AS Previous , @reav := r.`Present`
FROM (
    SELECT sg.Name AS `Customer NAME`, 
    m.meter_id AS `SERIAL NO`, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DATETIME, '%Y/%m/%d') AS `DATE`,  
    MAX(wh_total) AS `Present`
    FROM meter_data m 
    INNER JOIN enrollment e 
    ON e.Meter_Id = m.meter_id AND e.Status = 1 
    INNER JOIN company_subgroup sg 
    ON sg.Id = e.Subgroup_Id 
    INNER JOIN company_group g 
    ON g.Id = sg.Group_Id 
    WHERE DATE(DATETIME) BETWEEN '2018/06/01' AND '2018/06/30' 
    AND m.meter_id = '12345' 
    AND m.wh_total < 1000000000 
    GROUP BY DATE(DATETIME)
) AS r
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev:=0) AS INIT;
```

Comment: i have change my answer to correct 2 SQL typo errors

Comment: Why is @prev for Previous always 0?

Comment: @KPA - sorry, i cant see the error in this moment. can you please store some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: The result with that query is same as the result in my post but with all Previous row = 0, so it's not getting the previous row value.

Comment: @KPA - i have change my answer again. I hope its work now. the MAX function got the error